# Adding two dynamic variable and store it in INT type column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've two dynamic variable ...

```
 declare @count nvarchar(max)
 declare @totalCount int
 set @count = ' ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+ @Table +' where [Name] = '''+ CAST(@Name as           nvarchar(max)) +''' ) ' 
 set @totalCount = CAST(CAST(@count as nvarchar(max)) + CAST(@Qty as nvarchar(max)) as INT);
```

I'm getting an error

```
  conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to datatype int....
```

then I need to store @totalCount in [TotalCount] column of type INT ...PLease help

Answer (score 1):

he variable table name requires using dynamic SQL.  The example below assigns the computed value to the @totalCount variable using a parameterized query output parameter.

```
DECLARE
      @totalCount int
    , @Qty int = 5
    , @Sql nvarchar(MAX)
    , @Table sysname = 'Table'
    , @Name nvarchar(MAX) = N'Name';

SET @Sql = N'SELECT @totalCount = COUNT(*) + @Qty 
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + ' where [Name] = @Name;';

EXEC sp_executesql
      @Sql
    , N'@Name nvarchar(MAX), @Qty int, @totalCount int OUTPUT'
    , @Name = @Name
    , @Qty = @Qty
    , @totalCount = @totalCount OUT;
```